# Close or redirect tab on successful google authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, google-authentication, dancer

I have a project written in perl-dancer and angular. Im using google as a openId system.

Some of my pages have an edit grid with a save button. In order to avoid loosing unsaved data on session(session created from perl-dancer) expire, I have an angular interceptor which listens to 401 server errors and opens an angular modal holding the "google login" button(this is triggered on server request after session expire).

I have set the opening of google form on a new tab instead of redirect from original page in order to avoid loosing the possibly unsaved data.

On successful google authentication  the new tab redirects to the project homepage and the original stays with the open modal holding the "google login" button.

Ok now the new tab can be closed and on the original window the modal closed and the unsaved data is still there.

But this poor solution as result of not being allowed to embed the google login form or similar seems as a terrible solution from the user experience point of view.

Solutions, suggestions, help?!

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to check `$state` (or some other service) in the interceptor so you could set a flag in localStorage that indicates user has data being processed.

Then have a special route for this situation that just tells user to close the window and keep editing/saving in the previous window they have open

There would then be several different ways within the app start up you could check localStorage for this flag in order to redirect to that special route.

Within controller of that route clear the localStorage flag. You could even use `localStorage events` to close the modal in previous window automatically